# insert a new row if doesnot exists depending on the colum value in other row of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns (id,col_id,type_id,value) which looks like below

```
| id | col_id | type_id | value    |  
------------------------------------
| 1  | 152    | 22      | DGL      |
| 2  | 152    | 27      | AD56JK-5 |
| 3  | 152    | 30      | 5708     |
| 4  | 154    | 22      | JVM      |
| 5  | 154    | 27      | AD29JL-9 |
| 6  | 154    | 30      | 9584     |
| 7  | 155    | 22      | MVR      |
| 8  | 155    | 27      | AD29JM-1 |
```

What I want to do is for each distinct `col_id` change the value of row with type_id=30 as value of row with type_id=22+value of col_id.
For Example the value '5708' should be changed as 'DGL152' and the value '9584' should be changed as 'JVM154'. In the case of col_id=155 there is no row with type_id=30, then we should insert a new row with following values

```
------------------------------------
| 9  | 155    | 30      | MVR155   |
------------------------------------
```

There are many records like this in the table. In this way we should change the value of rows with type_id=30 or insert the row if it does not exist for all the records in the table. How could I do this? Could any body help me with a solution.

**Edit:**
I know how to set the update the value using UPDATE and SET but what I a looking for is do the entire updating and inserting process in single query.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: Your sample data has 3 distinct col_id 152,154 and 155. After the update, u want 3 records to be inserted into the table, is it so?

Comment: For just 155, if Record with 30 not present, than the insert should occur. And then the Update. Do u want it like

Comment: no, I want the records to be updated if already exists and to be inserted if it doesn't. In this case I want to update row with col_id 152,154 and insert a row with col_id 155

Comment: Last Question, If we did not find the record (id = 30) in table, where should we get it?
For 155, u typed it directly. As a whole where do we get the "30 records"

Comment: we assign the value as concat of value of type_id=22 and the distinct col_id for every record with type_id=30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To either insert or update, use the INSERT statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause. There must be a unique index on col_id + type_id to make it work.

```
insert into mytable (col_id, type_id, value)
  select col_id, 30 as type_id, concat(value, col_id) as new_value 
  from mytable src 
  where type_id = 22
on duplicate key update value = src.new_value;
```

Comment: do you want me to literally use this query or add some thing

Comment: What should be added? The statement selects all "22" records and tries to use them to insert "30" records. When this fails because a "30" record already exists, the "30" record will get updated. This is all. You don't need anything else. Except for a COMMIT of course ;-)

Comment: don't take me wrong I am new to SQL. When I ran this query in sql it gave me an error Unknown column 'src.new_value' in 'field list'. So I asked.

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't happen. You did change **mytable** to your table name, yes?

Comment: Yes, I did change it.

Comment: Well, maybe MySQL is strict as to what columns exists in the table itself and which are computed. Please replace `src.new_value` with `values(new_value)`. This may work.

Comment: And there is no unique index for the value in my table. do you think it's the reason it didn't work

Comment: No unique index? But it is the table's natural key! You should have this index regardless of whether you want to use my statement. How else would you guarantee not to have two different entries for one col_id + type_id?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. (It is in TSQL, but you will understand how it works.)

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT,COL_ID INT,TYPE_ID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES 
(1,152,22,'DGL152'),
(2,152,27,'AD56JK-5'),
(3,152,30,'5708'),
(4,154,22,'JVM154'),
(5,154,27,'AD29JL-9'),
(6,154,30,'9584'),
(7,155,22,'MVR'),
(8,155,27,'AD29JM-1')

UPDATE  A
SET     A.VALUE = B.VALUE
FROM    @TAB A
JOIN    @TAB B ON A.COL_ID = B.COL_ID
WHERE   A.TYPE_ID = 30
AND     B.TYPE_ID = 22

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

Result:

[image]

After the update, Write an INSERT statement for the new record.

```
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES (9,155,30,'MVR155')
```

---

Edit:

I read the question wrong,. If that is the case we may use a `MERGE`. Like this.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),COL_ID INT,TYPE_ID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES 
(152,22,'DGL152'),
(152,27,'AD56JK-5'),
(152,30,'5708'),
(154,22,'JVM154'),
(154,27,'AD29JL-9'),
(154,30,'9584'),
(155,22,'MVR'),
(155,27,'AD29JM-1')

MERGE @TAB A
USING (SELECT * FROM @TAB WHERE TYPE_ID = 22) B 
ON A.COL_ID = B.COL_ID AND A.TYPE_ID = 30

WHEN MATCHED AND A.TYPE_ID = 30 THEN UPDATE SET
VALUE = B.VALUE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(COL_ID,TYPE_ID,VALUE)
VALUES (B.COL_ID,B.TYPE_ID,B.VALUE);

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

Result:

[image]

It is TSQL by the way.

Comment: Actually there are many records in the table. I just showed only a few records. It is lot of process to update the entire table in this way. Any way thanks for trying..

Comment: It will work for any number of records. I doubt only the insert statement.

Comment: yes, it does update entire table I do know that. What I am looking is specifically for insert query or do the both insert and update in single query.

Answer (score 0):

```
update b
set b.VALUE = a.VALUE + CONVERT (varchar(5), a.TYPE_ID)
from TABULAR a 
join TABULAR b
on a.COL_ID = b.COL_ID 
where b.[TYPE_ID] = '30' and a.TYPE_ID = '22'
```

use an insert statement if the TYPE_ID = 30 doest exist